# How to burn iso image to DVD using dd command

Tags: dvd, burning

I was looking at the command to burn iso image to a dvd. But I couldnt get the name of the device. In the `/dev/` I could see `cdrom`,`cdrw`,`dvd`,`dvdrw`. I am using debian.

When I gave the command, I got the following output

```
dd if=debian-6.0.7-i386-DVD-1.iso of=/dev/dvdrw 
dd: opening `/dev/dvdrw': Read-only file system
```

Comment: You can't burn a cd with dd.

Comment: I have been burning iso images to DVD's and CD's for more than 35years.
It is only in recent (past 6-7 years) incarnations (versions) of dd
that it fails to write on blank media.
So, the driver has been modified to not allow dd to write on blank media. Since other apps (like k3b) CAN write to blank media, I suggest that
users hack the source code of such gui apps and look at what they do
to enable writing to blank media, and create a dd-like command to
get back the old functionality of dd.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can't use `dd` this way (it might work for DVD-RAM though). What you are looking for is `growisofs` - (the main) part of [dvd+rw-tools](http://fy.chalmers.se/~appro/linux/DVD+RW/).

```
growisofs -Z /dev/dvdrw=image.iso
```

Answer (score 11):

Using `dd` command you can not write DVD.
You can write DVD using `growisofs` command.

First you have to create ISO Using `dd` command like

```
dd if=/dev/dvd of=my_test.iso bs=2048
```

Then write DVD Using this command

```
growisofs -dvd-compat -Z /dev/dvd=my_test.iso
```

Answer (score 8):

I believe `growisofs` uses `dd`, so the original command could work.
My example uses a 22G image to bluray.
Here is the output of growisofs using the dry-run option:

```
growisofs -dry-run -speed=1 -Z /dev/sr0=/snd/BDSV_3E.iso
```

return:

```
Executing 'builtin_dd if=/snd/BDSV_3E.iso of=/dev/sr0 obs=32k seek=0'
```

You can experiment. I suggest using cheaper DVDs or CDs