# How do I get my DVD-RW to mount as a writable device instead of ROM?

Tags: devices, disk, automounting, readonly, dvd

I am trying to use my laptop (running Debian Jessie) and an external USB DVD reader/writer to burn an ISO to a DVD-RW.

However, upon inserting my disk, it appears to have been detected as read-only:

```
# lsblk
NAME                   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
sr0                     11:0    1 700.1M  0 rom
```

The following appears in dmesg when I connect the reader:

```
[10549.386006] usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 10 using xhci_hcd
[10549.522596] usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=152e, idProduct=2571
[10549.522618] usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[10549.522634] usb 1-1: Product: External USB DVDRW Drive
[10549.522647] usb 1-1: Manufacturer: HLDS Inc
[10549.522660] usb 1-1: SerialNumber: DA00000000000000100
[10549.524138] usb-storage 1-1:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[10549.525467] scsi5 : usb-storage 1-1:1.0
[10551.538610] scsi 5:0:0:0: CD-ROM            HL-DT-ST DVDRAM GP30NB30  1.00 PQ: 0 ANSI: 0
[10551.625316] sr0: scsi3-mmc drive: 24x/24x writer dvd-ram cd/rw xa/form2 cdda tray
[10551.626540] sr 5:0:0:0: Attached scsi CD-ROM sr0
[10551.627054] sr 5:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 5
```

How do I get this DVD to mount in such a way that I can actually write to it?

Comment: @don_crissti GNOME disks partition manager seems to think otherwise :/

Comment: Do you want to burn an ISO image  (check out the `wodim` command) or were you wanting to use a packet writing type of write access.  That would be a UDF type filesystem, which I have to admit I've never played with

Comment: @infixed I was using 'dd' to write slackware's installation ISO to the DVD, but it doesn't seem to have worked, so I went back and checked  GNOME didks, which claimed it was a read only filesystem.

Comment: @don_crissti wouldn't boot on the system I was trying to run it on. It also won't automount on my main system, so I assumed that my contents had not been written  - in GNOME disks, it appears as a blank disk, and read only, so it must be unable to write to it. I've just checked in gparted, too and gparted won't even show the disk.

Comment: There are a lot of details that go into making a good disk, such as cue and finalization.  `wodim` is a fork of `cdrecord` for debian, since they had issues with new licensing with `cdrecord`  there is also a `growisofs`.  But I I don't think you can get a valid DVD by just blasting it with `dd`

Comment: This may be a duplicate of http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68426/how-to-burn-iso-image-to-dvd-using-dd-command

Answer (score 2):

This question looks indeed like a duplicate of
[question 68426](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68426).
But the answers there are partly wrong in respect to `dd`.

The fact that Linux reports the drive as CD-ROM does not indicate that
it cannot be used for writing. CD-ROM is just one of the drive's many jobs.
Yours is obviously an LG DVD burner. Classified by Linux as "24x/24x writer".

Whether you can write to an optical medium by help of `dd` depends on
the medium type:

Formatted CD-RW, formatted DVD-RW, DVD-RAM, DVD+RW, BD-RE,
and BD-R in modes POW or RRM are supposed to work with `dd`.
These media behave in many ways like slow hard disks or giant floppies.
Linux would be willing to mount them writable if you put a writable
filesystem on it. E.g. `ext2` or `FAT`.
(But Don't ! Performance is awful. Media wear-off is terrible.
 Use burn programs or `dd` to write them.)

Before `dd` works on newly purchased media, formatting has to be done once by `dvd+rw-format` or
one of the burn programs below. (`dvd+rw-format` is the formatter 
companion of `growisofs`.)

CD-R, unformatted DVD-RW or CD-RW, DVD-R, DVD-R DL, DVD+R, DVD+R DL, and
BD-R in mode SRM can only be written by help of a burn program. Candidates
in Debian Jessie are on command line `wodim` for CD, `growisofs` for DVD/BD,
`cdrskin`, `xorriso` for CD/DVD/BD. GUI programs are `xfburn`, `brasero`,
`k3b` and possibly some more.